# Cloning divs and replacing id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hoping this isnt a repeat question as I could not find an answer.

I have a div that I need cloned.

```
<div class="phoneBookEntriesContainer">
    content here
</div>
```

I have to add an ID afterwards...dont ask :P.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
$(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").attr("id","phoneBookEntries" + i);
var doSomething = function(){

    $(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").attr("id","phoneBookEntries" + i);
    $("#phoneBookEntries" + i).clone().insertAfter("#phoneBookEntries" + i);

    i ++;
};
</script>
```

The code above kinda works, but instead of giving my divs unique id's, it replaces all of them with the same id.

So at the start I would have one `#phoneBookEntries1` div, after clicking the button to run the function I have two `#phoneBookEntries2` divs etc etc.

Comment: Why are you adding the ID to the original element using Javascript, rather than just defining it in the HTML?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: He is dynamically cloning the element and wants the new element to have a unique ID

Comment: @xbonez I understand what he's attempting to do. However, in order to clone an element, it has to exist beforehand. In this case, it does - he's defining his original element in HTML, then he's using Javascript to give it an ID. I want to know **why** he's doing it that way, because it makes no sense given the information provided in the question.

Comment: The site that I am working on uses uitags. For that reason (a very crappy reason :P) I was unable to put an ID on to the div without changing the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".phoneBookEntriesContainer")` returns an array of all DOM elements that have the class `phoneBookEntriesContainer`. Thus when you use `attr`, it replaces the id on all of those elements. If you want to replace it on a specific element only, you need to specify which one.

You can do that in the following ways:

```
//picks the last instance
$(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").last().attr("id","phoneBookEntries" + i);

//picks the last instance
$(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").first().attr("id","phoneBookEntries" + i);

//picks the 3rd instance
//.eq() is 0-indexed
$(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").eq(2).attr("id","phoneBookEntries" + i);
```

To achieve what you want, you should loop over all elements using jQuery's `.each()` method. For details, see Hidde's answer.

If you want to clone your div and give it a new ID everytime, use a variable to keep track of the number to be appended.

**[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/uEZXe/4/)**

This is the Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var currentID = 1;

        $('button').on('click',function(){
            currentID++;
            $('.foobar')
                .first()
                .clone()
                .appendTo('#wrapper')
                .attr('id','span' + currentID)
                .text('This has an ID of ' + currentID);

        });

});​
```

Comment: Sorry to ask.  What should my function look like exactly? I need the div to clone every time I click a button and the id should increment. I'm quite new to jquery and javascript and have a headache from staring at this white screen already lol.

Comment: Or use an ID selector because the original `<div>` (the one to be cloned) already has one before the function is executed.

Comment: Thanks! Tweaked it a little and it worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looping over each `.phoneBookEntriesContainer`:

```
$(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").each (function (i, el) {
    el.attr('id', ('phoneBookEntries' + (i+1)));
});
```

Comment: @jbabey Perfect if your elements already exist, not so great if you're appending them one by one. Iterating over all the elements and assigning a property every time you add an element would be excessive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [length](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp) property to get the total number of elements and append that to your ID prefix like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="phoneBookEntriesContainer">
    content here
</div>

<a href="#" class="cloneDiv">Click to Clone</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Bind to Clone Button //
$('.cloneDiv').bind('click', function(e){  

    // Prevent Default Action //
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create Clone //
    var $clone = $('.phoneBookEntriesContainer').filter(':last').clone();

    // Create Unique ID using Length //
    var cloneID = 'phoneBookEntries'+$('.phoneBookEntriesContainer').length;

    // Append to Body and Add Unique ID //
    $clone.attr('id', cloneID);
    $('.phoneBookEntriesContainer').filter(':last').after($clone);
});​
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ex7JF/1/)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
// set first container id
$(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").attr("id","phoneBookEntries1");

// on button click
$("#mybutton").click(function(){
    // calculate the new ID as phoneBookEntries count + 1
    var newID = "phoneBookEntries" + ($("div[id^='phoneBookEntries']").size() + 1);
    // insert the new div after the last one
    $("<div id='"+newID+"'></div>").insertAfter($("div[id^='phoneBookEntries']").last());
    // add the class to the divs which doesn't have it
    $("div[id^='phoneBookEntries']").addClass("phoneBookEntriesContainer");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

javascript :

```
var myFuntion = function(){
   var id = '' + $('.content').children().length;
   $('.content').append("<div class='phoneBookEntriesContainer' id='"+ id +"'></div>");
}
```

it will add your entries in the .content div with

Answer (score 0):

Your code seemed a bit confusing so I created a very verbose version here: http://jsfiddle.net/SY3aA/2/

Click the content in the working example and it adds another (you will want to modify that I would think)

First off, I give your first one an Id attribute with 0;
I put some class add/remove in so you could see what was going on.
I added text for that same purpose to reflect THAT added elements id.

```
var i = 1;
$(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").attr("id", "phoneBookEntries0");

var doSomething = function() {
    var myclone = $(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").eq(0).clone();
    $(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").removeClass("lastAdd imprev");

    var myentry = 'phoneBookEntries' + i;
    var myPrevEntry = '#phoneBookEntries' + (i - 1);
    var prev = $(myPrevEntry);
    prev.addClass('imprev');
    myclone.attr('id', myentry).insertAfter(prev);
    $('#' + myentry).text($('#' + myentry).text() + myentry);
    //this toggle seemed confusing so I changed it
    $('#' + myentry).addClass("lastAdd");

    i++;
}

$(document).on("click", '.phoneBookEntriesContainer', function() {
    $(".phoneBookEntriesContainer").removeClass("mydiv");
    $(this).addClass('mydiv');
    doSomething();
});
```

with this CSS:

```
.mydiv{border:solid 1px lime;}
.lastAdd{background-color:aqua;}
.imprev{border:solid blue 2px;}
```